# How to install an etcd cluster on a single host using docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bitnami, etcd

My host is a Macbook Pro 14 M1 Pro and this is the docker-compose.yml file I wrote, but when I use docker-compose up -d to start it, I always get all kinds of errors.

docker version

```bash
~ » docker version
Client:
 Version:           24.0.2
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.4
 Git commit:        cb74dfc
 Built:             Thu May 25 21:51:16 2023
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           orbstack

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.2
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.4
  Git commit:       659604f9ee60f147020bdd444b26e4b5c636dc28
  Built:            Sat May 27 17:14:34 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.7.1
  GitCommit:        1677a17964311325ed1c31e2c0a3589ce6d5c30d
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.7
  GitCommit:        860f061b76bb4fc671f0f9e900f7d80ff93d4eb7
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  etcd1:
    image: bitnami/etcd:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: etcd1
    environment:
      - ETCD_NAME=etcd1
      - ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS=http://etcd1:12380
      - ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS=http://etcd1:12379
      - ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS=http://etcd1:12379
      - ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS=http://etcd1:12380
      - ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TOKEN=etcd-cluster
      - ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER=etcd1=http://etcd1:12380,etcd2=http://etcd2:22380,etcd3=http://etcd3:32380
      - ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TIMEOUT=5000
      - ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE=new
      - ALLOW_NONE_AUTHENTICATION=yes
    volumes:
      - etcd_data1:/bitnami/etcd
    ports:
      - 12379:12379
    networks:
      - tsp_etcd

  etcd2:
    image: bitnami/etcd:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: etcd2
    environment:
      - ETCD_NAME=etcd2
      - ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS=http://etcd2:22380
      - ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS=http://etcd2:22379
      - ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS=http://etcd2:22379
      - ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS=http://etcd2:22380
      - ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TOKEN=etcd-cluster
      - ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER=etcd1=http://etcd1:12380,etcd2=http://etcd2:22380,etcd3=http://etcd3:32380
      - ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TIMEOUT=5000
      - ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE=new
      - ALLOW_NONE_AUTHENTICATION=yes
    volumes:
      - etcd_data2:/bitnami/etcd
    ports:
      - 22379:22379
    networks:
      - tsp_etcd

  etcd3:
    image: bitnami/etcd:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: etcd3
    environment:
      - ETCD_NAME=etcd3
      - ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS=http://etcd3:32380
      - ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS=http://etcd3:32379
      - ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS=http://etcd3:32379
      - ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS=http://etcd3:32380
      - ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TOKEN=etcd-cluster
      - ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER=etcd1=http://etcd1:12380,etcd2=http://etcd2:22380,etcd3=http://etcd3:32380
      - ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TIMEOUT=5000
      - ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE=new
      - ALLOW_NONE_AUTHENTICATION=yes
    volumes:
      - etcd_data3:/bitnami/etcd
    ports:
      - 32379:32379
    networks:
      - tsp_etcd

networks:
  tsp_etcd:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  etcd_data1:
    driver: local
  etcd_data2:
    driver: local
  etcd_data3:
    driver: local
```

I get the error:

```
etcd 02:39:46.57 Welcome to the Bitnami etcd container
etcd 02:39:46.57 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
etcd 02:39:46.57 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
etcd 02:39:46.57 
etcd 02:39:46.57 INFO  ==> ** Starting etcd setup **
etcd 02:39:46.58 INFO  ==> Validating settings in ETCD_* env vars..
etcd 02:39:46.58 WARN  ==> You set the environment variable ALLOW_NONE_AUTHENTICATION=yes. For safety reasons, do not use this flag in a production environment.
etcd 02:39:46.58 INFO  ==> Initializing etcd
etcd 02:39:46.58 INFO  ==> Generating etcd config file using env variables
etcd 02:39:46.59 INFO  ==> Detected data from previous deployments
/opt/bitnami/scripts/libetcd.sh: line 427: ETCD_ACTIVE_ENDPOINTS: unbound variable
etcd 02:39:46.60 INFO  ==> Adding new member to existing cluster
{"level":"warn","ts":"2023-06-21T02:39:51.624789Z","logger":"etcd-client","caller":"v3@v3.5.9/retry_interceptor.go:62","msg":"retrying of unary invoker failed","target":"etcd-endpoints://0x40001be000/127.0.0.1:2379","attempt":0,"error":"rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = latest balancer error: last connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused\""}
Error: context deadline exceeded
```

Can you help me to check what is wrong with my file? Give me some advice, please!

Thanks!!!